# Overriding a static file of an app?

Tags: python, django, static, django-geoposition

I am trying out [`django-geoposition`](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition) (actually, django itself). I would like to use my own version of the static file `geoposition.js`. So under my project, I created a `static/geoposition/geoposition.js` ( `STATIC_ROOT` defined as `static` under project root ), with the alternate content I wanted. All works fine in local dev server.

But, when I run `python manage.py collectstatic`, the original one is copied over. I kind of understand why that would be. Now, the question is, how do I override this js file that comes with the app and use my own in its place? Unfortunately, this uses a widget and defines its `Media` files there rather than from a template, which I could have easily overridden and used my js content with a different name.

Comment: Use a different name for your `.js` or replace the original one or try to manipulate the order - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic

Answer (score 2):

You can easily extend this widget and override its media with your static files:

```
class MyGeoWidget(GeoPositionWidget):
     class Media:
         extend = False
         css = {
               'all': ('whatever.css',)
            }
         js = ('mygeoposition.js',)
```